# Subset data.table by another data.table without merging all columns

Tags: r, merge, data.table, subset

With data.table, I'd like to subset a table according to another one.

```
DT1 <- data.table( A = c(1:5,1:2), B = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3), C = c(1:3))
DT2 <- data.table( A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(1,3,1), D = c(4:6))
```

The output should contain only columns of the first table.

```
   A B C
1: 1 1 1
2: 2 3 1
3: 3 1 3
```

With the merge function I get columns of both table

```
merge(DT1, DT2, by = c("A", "B"))

       A B C D
    1: 1 1 1 4
    2: 2 3 1 5
    3: 3 1 3 6
```

Since my datasets have much more columns, I'm looking for a way to get the result without the merge function, but with the data.table syntax [i, j, by].
However, with subsetting the first table it doesn't merge correctly.

```
DT1[A %in% DT2[,A] & B %in% DT2[, B]]

       A B C
    1: 1 1 1
    2: 2 1 2    < wrong
    3: 3 1 3
    4: 2 3 1

DT1[A == DT2[,A] & B == DT2[, B]]
       A B C
    1: 1 1 1
    2: 3 1 3
    Warning messages:
    1: In A == DT2[, A] :
      longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
    2: In B == DT2[, B] :
      longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Is there a way to get the correct rows like with merge, but using the data.table Syntax [ ]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @akrun's answer, you can identify the rows in the join and use them to subset the table:

```
w = sort(DT1[DT2, on=.(A,B), which=TRUE, nomatch=0])
DT1[w]

#    A B C
# 1: 1 1 1
# 2: 3 1 3
# 3: 2 3 1
```

or more compactly

```
DT1[sort(DT1[DT2, on=.(A,B), which=TRUE, nomatch=0])]
```

If you want to keep rows in the order from DT2, don't sort; and if you want unmatched rows included, skip `nomatch=0`.

Answer (score 2):

We do a join and then subset

```
nm1 <- names(DT1)
DT1[DT2, on = .(A, B)][, ..nm1]
#   A B C
#1: 1 1 1
#2: 2 3 1
#3: 3 1 3
```

---

Also, this is a case of `semi_join` from `dplyr`

```
dplyr::semi_join(DT1, DT2, by = c('A', 'B'))
#  A B C
#1 1 1 1
#2 2 3 1
#3 3 1 3
```

Comment: Or `DT1[DT1[DT2, on=.(A,B), which=TRUE, nomatch=0]]`

Comment: @Frank Never thought about the `which` route.  Great option.  If you want to post as an answer, go ahead

Comment: smart way to join without keys. The on= argument is new for me. Thanks! How would it look like if the 2nd table has different column names like `DT3 <- data.table( E = c(1, 2, 3), F = c(1,3,1), D = c(4:6))`

Comment: @visu-l  In that case, you would od `DT1[DT3, on =.(A=E, B=F)]`

Comment: could you please explain the second chain `[, ..nm1]`. I found no documentation about ".."

Comment: @visu-l  It is a new feature in data.table.  Usually, we use `DT[, nm1, with = FALSE]`

Answer (score 2):

```
 setkey(DT1, A,B,C)
 DT1[DT2]
# not quite right
   A B C
1: 1 1 4
2: 2 3 5
3: 3 1 6
# so join just on the two shared columns
DT1[ DT2[,list(A,B)]  ]
   A B C
1: 1 1 1
2: 2 3 1
3: 3 1 3
```

Look at `DT2[,list(A,B)]` and see that naming the desired columns (without quotes) in a list is the usual method of getting subsets of columns.